# Copy files from Samba share in node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to copy files from Samba share in my application. The paths are in `smb://host/filename` format. How do I do it in nodejs? `fs.createReadStream` refuses to open these paths. I need to do this on both Windows and *nix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a Linux host (since you mentioned "samba" and not "MS SMB"), you'll first need to mount the remote server with `smbmount`. [This forum post has an overview of how to do that](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mounting-samba-share-11439/), then you just read the files as if they were local to your server.

Alternatively, [`smbget`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/smbget/) lets you acquire single files without mounting the remote host, but isn't efficient for a large number of file requests.

Another edit; some example code:

```
var remoteFile = require('child_process').spawn('smbget', ['--stdout', 'smb://host/filename']);
remoteFile.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
    //handle chunk of data
});
remoteFile.on('exit', function() {
    //file loaded completely, continue doing stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't specific enough, I need to copy files over smb protocol, without mounting those shares.

Comment: Another note: I can't find anything in the MSDN on smb utilities for Windows, so I don't think there's a cross-platform way of doing what you want to do (ironically not possible on SMB's home turf).

Comment: I think it can be done in windows just by converting the path from smb://host to \\host format. I'm still hoping there's a 'node' way of doing this without spawning OS processes.

Comment: Well, the "node" way would be implementing a library that uses the ``net`` object and directly implements the SMB protocol, but that's a large effort for little gain when you can check ``process.os()`` and either connect to the ``\\servername\path`` in Windows (as you suggest) or simply run ``smbget`` on Linux/Mac. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I guess our conversation was so informative that I just can not not approve your answer )